# Problema com ordenação por data com plugin DATATABLE

Tags: php, jquery, sql, datatable

Amigos, estou com problema na ordenação de uma tabela com plugin Datatable sendo que faço uma consulta SQL já ordenada por um campo e quando apresenta a tabela com o plugin ele reordena de outra forma e já tentei varias formas sem sucesso de resolver isso.

> SQL

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM $this->table ORDER BY date(data_cadastro) DESC";
```

> DataTable

```
var tabela = $('#Compras').dataTable( {
            "aoColumns": [  null,null,null,null,null,{ "bSortable": false },{ "bSortable": false },{ "bSortable": false },{ "bSortable": false },null,{ "bSortable": false } ],

            "oLanguage": {
            "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ".",
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
            "sProcessing": "Processando...",
            "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sNext": "Próximo",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                "sLast": "Último"
                }
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
            }

            });

        })
```

> PHP

```
<?=date("d/m/Y", strtotime($x->data_cadastro)) ?>
```

Retorno sql:

```
14/03/2018
14/03/2018
14/03/2018
13/03/2018
12/03/2018
```

Resultado na tabela:

```
14/03/2018
14/03/2018
13/03/2018
12/03/2018
14/03/2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Thiago, a ordenação no datatable se dá pelo padrão (ano-mês-dia).

Na coluna que contém a data, você pode fazer:

```
<tr>
    <td data-order="DATAPADRAO">DATA_BR</td>
</tr>
```

[Mais info](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html")

Answer (score 0):

Diante de varias tentativas encontrei uma solução agradavel, porém gera um erro que nao consegui decifrar ainda, mas o resultado é o que preciso.

```
"aaSorting": [[6, 'DESC']],
```

esta forma consigo ordenar pelo numero da coluna o formato data

```
"order": [[6, 'DESC']],
```

não funciona.

> o erro gerado

```
jquery.dataTables.min.js:84 Uncaught TypeError: p[((intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) + "-" + o[c][1])] is not a function
```

alguem sabe me ajudar a excluir este erro !!!